# C# Не видит объявленный List<BitArray>

Tags: c#, list

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    class Structure
    {
        List<BitArray> signals = new List<BitArray>();

    }
}
```

Хочу заполнить signals, но не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И где вы  его заполняете? Весь код дайте.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Structure
{
  public List<BitArray> signals = new List<BitArray>();

  public Structure()
  {
    signals.Add(new BitArray(200));
  }
}


Structure s = new Structure();
s.signals.Add(new BitArray(100));
```

---

> У меня там статические данные.

```
  static List<BitArray> signals = new List<BitArray>();
```

Comment: А что если я хочу заполнить LIst внутри класса? У меня там статические данные.

Comment: @DmitryMachikhelyan "У меня там статические данные." - ??

Comment: Хочу в нём хранить в этом листе хранить код Грейя.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо подключить пространство имен и класс BitArray, 
проверьте Ваши 
using 
вверху над
namespace WindowsFormsApp2